# Using mmdetection problem_even demo test

Tags: faster-rcnn

```
raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'FasterRCNN' object has no attribute 'show_result'`
```

i searched "AttributeError: 'FasterRCNN' object has no attribute 'show_result'"

I'm new to programming, so I'm not sure what the problem is... I'm sorry

```
from mmdet.apis import init_detector, inference_detector
from PIL import Image  
config_file = './mmdetection/configs/faster_rcnn/faster-rcnn_r50_fpn_1x_coco.py'
checkpoint_file = './mmdetection/checkpoint/faster_rcnn_r50_fpn_1x_coco_20200130-047c8118.pth'
device = 'cuda:0'
model = init_detector(config_file, checkpoint_file, device=device)

test_img = './mmdetection/demo/demo.jpg'
result = inference_detector(model, test_img)

model.show_result(test_img, result, out_file='./result.jpg')

img = Image.open(test_img)
img2 = Image.open('./result.jpg')
img.show()
img2.show()`
```